# can anyone show me a very simple example of unix script loop

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, loops, exit

I just need an example of script that repeat all the same actions in a loop til we ask to stop it. Say I want the user to type y or n for exit, how would i implement it. I have something like 
echo "Input y or n to exit"
read input
if [ "$input = y ]
then
.......
else
........
fi

For the same script demonstrated in the answer below or maybe other example, how can I have this addition to make the user control the script without having to exit only by pressing control+z

Comment: If you want the loop to continue running in the background, ^z followed by bg is appropriate.  If you want to terminate the loop, you want ^c.  (ctrl-C instead of ctrl-Z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while true; do
   commands ...

   read -p "Continue (y/n) ? " answer
   case "$answer" in
      Y*|y*) : ;;
      *) break
   esac
done
```

If the user responds with "Y" or "y", do nothing, in which case the loop continues.  Otherwise break the loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
while true; do echo hello; sleep 1; done
```

will run until you send a signal.

Comment: How can the user gain control of the loop without pressing control+z?

Comment: If you are on a *nix machine, ctrl-c sends SIGINT.  ctrl-z sends SIGSTOP and should not be used in this case.  What do you mean by "gain control of the loop"?  It is not clear to me what you are trying to do.  Perhaps glenn jackman's answer is what you are looking for.